# XSLT: Get Month Abbreviation

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a string that represents a date and is formatted like so

2010-12-03 = "yyyy-mm-dd"

I would like to use XSLT and find a way to extract the month and get its month abbreviation.

After the transform it should read "**DEC**" since December is the 12th month.

Thanks!

Comment: Given that you're using XSLT 1.0, I would suggest a lookup table `<months><month n="1" abbrev="JAN" /><month n="2" abbrev="FEB"/>...` and then look up the abbrev using `$months/month[@n = number(substring-before(substring-after($datestr, '-'), '-'))]`.

Comment: would I need to put thistable in a seperate file. The xml I am receiving is pretty extensive

Comment: @nholloway4, See my answer for a full implementation of the same approach as proposed by LarsH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is a short demo how to do this intelligently and efficiently:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:param name="pMonthNames">
  <name><short>JAN</short>January</name>
  <name><short>FEB</short>February</name>
  <name><short>MAR</short>March</name>
  <name><short>APR</short>April</name>
  <name><short>MAY</short>May</name>
  <name><short>JUN</short>June</name>
  <name><short>JUL</short>July</name>
  <name><short>AUG</short>August</name>
  <name><short>SEP</short>September</name>
  <name><short>OCT</short>October</name>
  <name><short>NOV</short>November</name>
  <name><short>DEC</short>December</name>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:variable name="vMonthNames" select=
     "document('')/*/xsl:param[@name='pMonthNames']/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="t">
     <xsl:value-of select="$vMonthNames[position()=substring(current(),6,2)]/short"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>2010-12-03</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
DEC
```

Answer (score 8):

You can just add this to your XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="months" select="'  JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC'" />
```

Then wherever you need the month abbreviation, use this:

```
substring($months, substring(date, 6, 2) * 3, 3)
```

where `date` would be a reference to your node with a date in it.

Comment: Thanks! I think this will work. I also found an EXSLT function to get the abbreviation I needed to make this occur in an integration tool we use